# How do I bypass Rails.cache for a single request or code block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activesupport

I have an API endpoint that aggregates a bunch of data from code that leverages Rails.cache for small pieces of data here and there.  There are times, however, when I want 100% up-to-date data, as if Rails.cache was empty.  Obviously I could clear cache prior to aggregating the data, but that will affect unrelated data and requests.

Is there a way for me to have a request in rails act as if Rails.cache is empty, similar to if Rails.cache was configured to be :null_store?

The query cache in ActiveRecord has something like this - an "uncached" function that you can pass a block to, where the block will run w/o query cache enabled.  I need something similar, but for Rails.cache in general.

Comment: which Rails api are you using to cache the data in the first place?

Comment: I am using rails 3.2.17.  The cache is the standard Rails.cache - defined in rails.rb within the railties gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it does not appear there is a solution to this out of the box, I coded a solution of my own by adding the following code as config/initializers/rails_cache.rb

```
module Rails
  class << self
    alias :default_rails_cache :cache
    def cache
      # Allow any thread to override Rails.cache with its own cache implementation.
      RequestStore.store[:rails_cache] || default_rails_cache
    end
  end
end
```

This allows any thread to specify its own cache store, which will then be used for all fetches, reads, and writes.  As such, it will not read from the default Rails.cache, nor will its values be written to the default Rails.cache.

If the thread is long-running and benefits from having caching enabled, you can easily set this to its own MemoryStore instance:

```
RequestStore.store[:rails_cache] = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_store)
```

And if you want caching completely off for this thread, you can :null_store instead of :memory_store.

If you are not using the request_store gem, "RequestStore.store" can be replaced with "Thread.current" for the same effect - just have to be more careful about thread reuse across requests.